# Move points to a Z-value?

Tags: qgis, point, dxf, z-value, translate

I want to export a 800k points, which correspond to a DEM (terrain elevation) to Rhino.
Currently, I tried to export a CSV with X,Y,Z coordinates based on the point attributes, however, there seems to be an interpretation problem with the CRS during the import/export.
[image]

So now I want to move the points to their respective Z coordinate (which I got from the Saga "Add raster value to points" processing tool). How do I physically move the points? I tried the "Translate" processing algorithm, but that doesn't seem to move the points physically.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drape them onto the DEM:

[Drape (set Z value from raster)](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissetzfromraster)

> This algorithm sets the z value of every vertex in the feature
> geometry to a value sampled from a band within a raster layer.